# Returning the correct child type from a function

Tags: c++

I have a `UIComponent` class. `Window`, `Button` and `Text` inherit from it. `UIComponent` has a recursive structure in that it stores a `std::vector<std::unique_ptr<UIComponent>> contents;`. I am trying to write a function that recursively that goes through `contents` and finds the given `UIComponent`.

In my original code, I use a hash-table, but the following code very closely resembles what the original looks like (sorry if it's a bit long – I couldn't make it any shorter):

```
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <memory>
#include <iostream>

class UIComponent
{
public:
    std::string name = "";

    UIComponent() = default;

    std::vector<std::unique_ptr<UIComponent>> contents;

    UIComponent(const UIComponent& other) noexcept
    {
        for (auto& otherContent : other.contents)
        {
            contents.push_back(
                std::make_unique<UIComponent>(*otherContent)//recursive call
            );
        }
    }

    template <
        template <class> class Component,
        class Fx
    >
        void Attach(const Component<Fx>& comp, std::string name)
    {
        contents.push_back(
            std::move(std::make_unique<Component<Fx>>(comp))
        );

        contents.back()->name = name;
    }

    //Should search all the components and return one that matches
    //the argument
    UIComponent* GetComponent(const std::string& name)
    {
        static UIComponent* pOut = nullptr;
        for (size_t i = 0; i < contents.size(); i++)
        {
            if (name == contents[i]->name)
            {
                pOut = contents[i].get();
                return pOut;
            }
        }

        if (pOut != nullptr)
        {
            return pOut;
        }

        for (auto& content : contents)
        {
            content->GetComponent(name);
        }

        return pOut;
    }

};

template < class Fx >
class Window : public UIComponent
{
public:
    Window() = default;
};

template < class Fx >
class Button : public UIComponent
{
public:
    Button() = default;
};

template < class Fx >
class Text : public UIComponent 
{
public:
    Text() = default;
};

Window<void(void)> window;
Button<void(void)> button;
Text<void(void)> text;

int main()
{
    window.Attach<Button, void(void)>(button, "button");
    button.Attach<Text, void(void)>(text, "text");

    auto b = window.GetComponent("button");
    if (b != nullptr)
    {
        std::cout << b->name << " : " << typeid(*b).name() << '\n';
    }

    auto t = window.GetComponent("text");
    if (t != nullptr)
    {
        std::cout << t->name << " : " << typeid(*t).name() << '\n';
    }
}
```

Actual Output:

```
button : class UIComponent
button : class UIComponent
```

Expected output:

```
button : class Button<void(void)>
text : Text<void(void)>
```

The function I am struggling with is `UIComponent* GetComponent(const std::string& name)`.

It always returns a `UIComponent*`. I am not sure how to make it so that tt returns the correct child class type. I am also not sure about the logic but that might not be strictly related to the question.

Comment: In the `UIComponent` copy constructor, `std::make_unique<UIComponent>(*otherContent);` slices by creating an object of actual type `UIComponent`, not a derived type. If you need polymorphic copies, implement a virtual `std::unique_ptr<UIComponent> clone() const { return std::make_unique<DerivedType>(*this); }` in each class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the polymorphic behaviour you are attempting to work, you need at least one of the base class member functions to be `virtual`.

In your code, simply adding that specifier to the `GetComponent` member function will do the trick; like this:

```cpp
    virtual UIComponent* GetComponent(const std::string& name)
    {
        // ... all other code as in the original.
```

With this simple edit, the output I see when I run your code is then<sup>1</sup>:

```
button : class Button<void __cdecl(void)>
button : class Button<void __cdecl(void)>
```

So, although you'll then need to do some 'tidying up' of the returned class names, you will at least get pointers that reflect the actual run-time objects.

But note: as you now have a virtual member function, you really ought to also make the destructor(s) `virtual`, as well: [When to use virtual destructors?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/461203/10871073) So, add this to the base class definition:

```cpp
    virtual ~UIComponent() = default;
```

---

<sup>1</sup> Edit: Note that, in your `main` function, there appears to be a conflict between the `window` and `button` objects, in terms of which one the "Text" control is attached to. The object in the `Attach` call and in the subsequent `GetComponent` call should be the same (they aren't in your original code). Here is an example of the `main` code edited so that they *are* the same, as follows:

```cpp
int main()
{
    window.Attach<Button, void(void)>(button, "button");
    button.Attach<Text, void(void)>(text, "text"); // NOTE: You are attaching to the button ...

    auto b = window.GetComponent("button");
    if (b != nullptr) {
        std::cout << b->name << " : " << typeid(*b).name() << '\n';
    }

    auto t = button.GetComponent("text"); // NOTE: Using "button.GetComponent"
    if (t != nullptr) {
        std::cout << t->name << " : " << typeid(*t).name() << '\n';
    }
}
```

The output is now (as expected):

```
button : class Button<void __cdecl(void)>
text : class Text<void __cdecl(void)>
```

Comment: It was intentional. I wanted window to check children of children of ... and so on and get the component no matter how deep it might be. Is it not possible to do that?

Comment: @fbi OK - that may need a bit more thinking about. I'll see what I can do. However, the `virtual` specifier is the basic solution to your original problem.

Comment: @fbi One issue that is likely causing some problems is the use of `name` as both an argument and a data member. Maybe change the argument to `arg_name`.

Comment: The comment made by aschepler on your question is an issue that needs addressing, for sure. I think if you fix that, you'll fix the recursion-related issues. Maybe though, in your actual real-world code, that problem doesn't present itself.